# How To Display Japanese Characters in ColdFusion With <cfoutput>

Tags: coldfusion, character-encoding, multibyte

I am creating a ColdFusion page with some Japanese characters. I included the following in the top of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If I explicitly include Japanese characters in the output, they look fine. However, if I output them using, say:

```
<cfoutput>#variables.TitleInJapanese#</cfoutput>
```

The output is garbled as though the encoding is not recognized. I have tried <cfcontent> and <cfprocessingdirective> tags to no avail.

If I open the .cfm source file, the Japanese characters that are assigned to the variables look as they should in my text editor. It's the content that is generated using <cfoutput> that is giving me trouble. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

**Correction:** The page I have created will not display any Japanese characters, explicit or referenced. However, other files using <cfinclude> within the page that have Japanese characters render just fine.

Comment: If you are actually assigning Japanese characters to variables that might be the issue. I had a vaguely similar problem once. Try replacing them with a unicode alternative and they should render on the page. http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Comment: Have you tried adding "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the end of the JVM Arguments? 

Screen shot: https://twitter.com/WebVeteran/status/738758510087950336